# Вычислить процент verticalNormalizedPosition для ScrollRect, что бы подгрузить данные с сервера

Tags: unity3d, scrollview

Есть вертикальный ScrollView с данными с сервера, контент создается размером от полученного количества записей с сервера, скажем 50 * на их размер + спейс. Но элементов в контенте фиксированное число, например 10 и сразу отображается количество данных с сервера на число элементов. Собственно, когда пользователь докручивает до конца последнего элемента, я запрашиваю с сервера новую пачку данных и **перемещаю**(меняю позицию) элементы с верхнего в низ, как бы продолжая список. Проблема в чем, как вычислить когда нужно подгрузить данные, тобишь как получить нужное значение для verticalNormalizedPosition скролла, когда пользователь прокрутил до последнего элемента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед добавлением вычисли актуальную позицию скрола в процентах 0.0-1.0 (делим позицию скрола на общею длину).
И новая позиция (в процентах) будет легко посчитать. Примерно так

```
НовыйПроцент = (ЧислоЭлементов*Процент)/(ЧислоЭлементов+ЧислоДобавляемыхЭлементов);
```

И умножаем новый процент на новую общую длину.

Comment: "Общая длина" чего, контента, элементов в нем?  
У меня элементы фиксированного количества скажем 10 и при запросе новой пачки я не добавляю еще элементы я просто двигаю самый верхний в низ, например пришла пачка на 5 новых элементов и я 5 самых верхних двигаю вниз и обновляю для них данные, при этом длина самого контента рассчитана на максимальное количество данных. Поэтому новая общая длина это длина от начала контента до последнего элемента или как?  
Также "число элементов" это число элементов, которые у меня есть или число всех возможных элементов?

Comment: "Общая длина" это "размер + спейс" имеющихся элементов. "число элементов" которые есть (до добавления новых).